# What is the little icon in the top left

Tags: notifications

The icon disappears when I'm using the phone.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, Reddy. What is your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Giffgaff (stylised "giffgaff") is a mobile telephone network running as a Mobile Virtual Network Operator using O2's British network. Owned by O2's owners Telefónica, Giffgaff was launched on 25 November 2009.

It is the Branding logo from your Mobile Telephone Network

From Wikipedia

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It only appeared today though and I've used giffgaff for several years. My hubby also has it and hasnt got the icon?

Comment: That seems strange... You can individually go through the notifications and identify the app inside settings.